# how to input and display multi lines in php/html form?

Tags: php, html, forms

So i am new to using Linux VPS. I want to install softether on my VPS to protect myself when i play online multiplayer games. My VPS does not have much DDOS protection (because it is cheap)so i learned a technique called IP tables. There seems to be a lot of bad ip addresses in many databases that I found online. So i started to block IPs, but found that it takes a long time. I wanted to write an IP table generator to make my life easier. I wanted to use a subnet calculator on this form but i did not know how to code it, so i use a online site to get the subnet ip addresses of an ip i going to block.I thought it might be easier to just block all corporate and commercial asn ip addresses. but again i don't know where to start.  That would be better for me to block ALL corporate/commercial IPs when i play my online games and i can just whitelist the IPs from my xbox live servers. please share your opinion(s). i want to have a safe time playing online without attackers flooding my internet.

i want to add multiple ip address inside my generator. but i cannot remember what shall I google to be able to learn how to do it. ALSO my php code is not working. 
MY AIM to add multiple ip address and config them to rules, filters and chain rules. AND display them at the bottom clean (with line breaks) .

```
    <html><head><style>.error {color: #FF0000;}</style></head><body>
    <?php
    $addressErr = $rulesErr = $filtersErr = $cRULEErr = "";
    $address = $rules = $filters = $cRULE = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $nameErr = "ip address is required";
      } else {
       $name = test_input($_POST["address"]);
     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]*$/",$address)) {
      $addressErr = "Only numbers and white space allowed";
       }
       }
       if (empty($_POST["rules"])) {
        $rules = "Rules is required";
        } else {
         $rules = test_input($_POST["rules"]);
         }
         }

         if (empty($_POST["filters"])) {
         $filters = "Filters is required";
          } else {
         $filters = test_input($_POST["filters"]);
          }
          }
          if(isset($_POST['generate'])){
          if(!empty($_POST['cRULE'])){
          foreach($_POST['cRULE'] as $selected){
             }
                 }
                     }


                function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
                   }

                 $data= $address + $rules + $filters + $cRULE + $selected."</br>";
               echo $data "</br>"
                  ?>
               <p>

              <form class="form-horizontal">
             <fieldset>

              <!-- Form Name -->
             <legend>ip Table Generator v1</legend>

              <!-- Text input-->
             <div class="form-group">
             <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="address">IP</label>  
             <div class="col-md-4">
             <input id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

             </div>
             </div>

             <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
             <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rules">RULES</label>
              <div class="col-md-4"> 
             <label class="radio-inline" for="rules-0">
              <input type="radio" name="rules" id="rules-0" value="ACCEPT" checked="checked">
                 accept
              </label> 
              <label class="radio-inline" for="rules-1">
              <input type="radio" name="rules" id="rules-1" value="DROP">
                drop
              </label> 
              <label class="radio-inline" for="rules-2">
              <input type="radio" name="rules" id="rules-2" value="RETURN">
              return
              </label>
               </div>
                  </div>

                <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filters">FILTERS</label>
                   <div class="col-md-4"> 
                  <label class="radio-inline" for="filters-0">
                   <input type="radio" name="filters" id="filters-0" value="INPUT" checked="checked">
                     input
                   </label> 
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="filters-1">
                      <input type="radio" name="filters" id="filters-1" value="FORWARD">
                      forward
                      </label> 
                         <label class="radio-inline" for="filters-2">
                      <input type="radio" name="filters" id="filters-2" value="OUTPUT">
                          output
                       </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                         <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cRULE">Chain Rules</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                   <label class="checkbox-inline" for="cRULE-0">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="cRULE" id="cRULE-0" value="APPEND">
                    -A (Append)
                      </label>
                     <label class="checkbox-inline" for="cRULE-1">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="cRULE" id="cRULE-1" value="INTERFACE">
                    -i (interface)
                      </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="cRULE-2">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="cRULE" id="cRULE-2" value="PROTOCOL">
                    -p (protocol)
                    </label>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="cRULE-3">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="cRULE" id="cRULE-3" value="SOURCE">
                       -s (source)
                       </label>
                     <label class="checkbox-inline" for="cRULE-4">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="cRULE" id="cRULE-4" value="dPORT">
                     –dport
                   </label>
                     <label class="checkbox-inline" for="cRULE-5">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="cRULE" id="cRULE-5" value="TARGET">
                   -j (target)
                      </label>
                       </div>
                     </div>

                   <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="GEN"></label></br>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                 <button id="GEN" name="GEN" class="btn btn-primary">GENERATE</button>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                   </fieldset>
                     </form>
```

Comment: if you are returning the result in a browser, line breaks have to be set with <br /> to display properly.
If you are generating a config file for linux, you need to use \n is your PHP strings. \n can be set either by just writing \n in a double-quoted string such as $text = "Hello,\nThis is a test";
Or using the PHP_EOL constant.

Comment: i installed a web server on the VPS for hosting. (so i can have multiple website)my issue is to input multiple ip address at the same time and add values and get the results tidy below the form. im not getting any output below.